# Java 8 lower bounded wildcard

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I'm preparing for OCP certificate, and I came across with the idea of a lower bounded wildcard. If I understand it correctly, the lower bounded wildcard is used when we want to let Java know the "bounded type" can always be added to our generic Collection.

For example:

```
public static void addInteger(List<? super Integer> list, Integer i)
{
    list.add(i);
}


public static void main(String[] args)
{   
    List<Number> list = new ArrayList<>();
    addInteger(list, 100);
    addInteger(list, 200);
    System.out.println(list);       // [100,200]

}
```

Since "? super Integer" indicates that the type must be an Integer or its superclass, adding an Integer to the list will work in each case.

However, this code still compiles and runs like normal:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{   
    Predicate<? super String> pred = s -> s.startsWith("M"); // still compiles
    System.out.println(pred.test("Mon")); // Output true

}
```

Now we have a Predicate that will take 1 parameter which is a String or its super class, but we're not sure it's actually a String or not (What if it's just an Object?). However, we can still access `startsWith()` method like `s` is actually a String.

Why does this happen? Please explain to me.

Comment: Have you tried this code: `System.out.println(pred.test(newObject()));` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Predicate<? super String> pred` can be assigned either a `Predicate<String>` or a `Predicate<Object>`. You are assigning to it a `Predicate<String>`, which is allowed. The compiler infers that `s -> s.startsWith("M")` is a `Predicate<String>` since you are using a `String` method in the lambda expression.

For example, the following will also pass compilation:

```
Predicate<? super String> pred = (Object o) -> o.hashCode() > 0;
```

You can also see that the following passes compilation:

```
Predicate<String> preds = s -> s.startsWith("M");
Predicate<Object> predo = (Object o) -> o.hashCode() > 0;
Predicate<? super String> pred = preds;
pred = predo;
```

i.e. `Predicate<? super String>` can be assigned both a `Predicate<String>` and a `Predicate<Object>`.

That said, note that `pred.test()` will only accept `String`s, and not any `Object`. The reason is that the `pred` variable can reference either a `Predicate<Object>` or `Predicate<String>` at runtime, and only a `String` is acceptable by both.

Comment: This makes so much sense. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Your seem to be confused about the difference between the type of the `Predicate` object instance (that is created by the lambda) and type of `pred`, the reference to that object.

- The `Predicate` instance that is created by the lambda has type `Predicate<String>`.
- The reference `pred` to the object is of type `Predicate<? super String>`, and can thus be assigned values of both type `Predicate<Object>` and `Predicate<String>`. But the `test` method of the predicate can only be called with `String` objects!

  That's what the `? super String` bound ensures.

Object instances always have type parameters of some concrete type, like `Object` or `String`. Only references to can have type parameters of wildcard types.